Do websites that tell email already in use violate privacy?
If there is a website that during sign up tells if some email is already in use when using that email, do they violate privacy? They're disclosing that someone is using that service if we know their email, while this is unavoidable, is there anything that could possibly be used against it?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


If there is a website that during sign up tells if some email is
already in use when using that email, do they violate privacy?

No.
The website isn't providing personally identifying information about a person. It is merely providing information about everyone, collectively, who isn't you. Someone out there must have that email, but it doesn't tell you who.
The website itself isn't sharing enough information, by itself, to learn something about the actual person. You also need a "private key" so to speak, that the website does not provide (in this situation, knowledge of who the email address belongs to).
There are lots of circumstances when information that doesn't violate privacy by itself can reveal information about someone if you have other private information that is not revealed to you from the same source.
For example, if you know how everyone else in a precinct voted, you can determine the way that the last person voted from the vote totals for that precinct.
If you want to know if your spouse has an account at a dating site, and your spouse doesn't want you to know that, your spouse should use an email account that you don't know about from a place or in a mode that prevents you from accessing your spouse's browsing history.
People routinely voluntarily share information that they could keep private because it is a route of least resistance to do so when the information shared isn't important. I don't have an ultra-secret complicated password for my Netflix account, and I'd be thrilled if someone hacked my utility bill account and paid my bill for me, so I don't keep my password for that very secure either. On the other hand, I have highly secure access to my bank accounts and use an email not traceable to me if I'm doing something I want to keep secret (as lawyers sometimes must).
Learning these lessons is part of modern life in the age of the Internet. But the fact that users share private information doesn't make it the website's fault that the private information shared makes it possible to learn thing that the website doesn't reveal is traced to you.
In the same vein, many people have a password that appears prominently on a sticky note on your computer screen. The site whose password is on the sticky note isn't responsible for breaches of your privacy that arise from someone in your office reading the sticky note, even if it is still wrong for the person who accesses your account with that password to do so without your permission.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes
Now, that may or may not be illegal because privacy laws differ widely around the world. However, looking at the “gold standard”, the EU’s GDPR, this is probably a violation.
In general, an email address and the fact that it’s owner is or is not a member of the site is Personal Data because it is “information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person (‘data subject’)”. A generic corporate email address might not be personal data if the people who have access to it is sufficiently large that they cannot be individually identified, but most web sites don’t or can’t make the distinction so they should treat all email addresses as personal data.
Disclosure of this information to a third-party (which is what the person typing an arbitrary email address in is), is a data breach.

Is there any authority supporting that interpretation of the Article 4 GDPR definition to include email addresses?

Surely a generic email address by itself, although relating to a "data subject," is not in and of itself considered identifying.  Because I would wager if I tried to create a new email account happycat@yahoo.com that somebody already has taken it.  Yet it is 100% anonymous if the holder of that email address wishes it to be...

@MichaelHall I think you might have interpreted the question to be about signing up for an email service, when it’s actually about using an email address to sign up for some other service.

@Sneftel, I did initially interpret it that way, but have since deleted my other comments around that.  I get the purpose now, and my latest comment may be NA since the gist of the question presumes prior knowledge of the owner of the email, but I think my question is legit WRT to an otherwise non-identifying and anonymous email.  But maybe that's a separate question?

@ohwilleke Yes, its explicity called out as such by the European Commission https://commission.europa.eu/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/what-personal-data_en

@MichaelHall The EU Commission disagress with you. See above.

The linked E.U. Commission policy sets forth two clear cases: (1) an email with someones name and surname in it, which is identifying information, and (2) an email like info@corporatename.com which is not. But many, if not most, are in between and have ambiguous status under that ruling, such as "FrenchRevolutionary@gmail.com". Of course, even if it is identifying information, it might fall within an exception within GDPR, for example, for information sharing necessary to operate a website (which doesn't necessarily require best practices). I push back because this practice is so ubiquitous.

@ohwilleke, for the purposes of the OP, the website doesn't know what sort it's dealing with. In any event, I think you're wrong and an email like "worldsgreatestlover@gmail.com", if its mine (which I will neither confirm nor deny) is personal information about me even though only Google has the data to link it to me.

But personal information about you is different than personal information that confirms your identity without requiring additional corroborating details to be included.  I have brown eyes, is that considered "personal information"?

@MichaelHall Yes, it is. Your brown eyes are personal information because they are linked to you. Brown eyes, in general, is not personal information because it is not linked to an individual. It becomes personal information when it is "this person has brown eyes". An email address that is used by an individual (or a small number of individuals) is personal information because it is linked to that person.
